# Apple magic trackpad 2 not recognized by mac

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, bluetooth, magic-trackpad

I have tried the following:

Connected to computer with usb-c to usb-a charging cable.

Charged Trackpad overnight while power is on and while power is off.

Reset the bluetooth

Removed all Bluetooth Devices

Reset PRAM

Tried to add to a MacMini

Nothing works.

Comment: The Trackpad could be dead.  Did you try it with other computers?  Do other BT devices work with your Mac?

Comment: how old is it ? and it is not showing on BT list ? When you start a Magic Trackpad, it announces itself over bluetooth : Does it ?

Comment: The Apple Magic TrackPad 2 can be used through wired USB, no Bluetooth required! ..so does it work ?

Answer (score 1):

- Make sure the Trackpad is powered on (there is a switch on the back)
- Make sure you are using the Trackpad with a Mac that has Bluetooth 4.0 and runs at least OS X v10.11
- Connect the Trackpad to your Mac with a USB to Lightning Cable
- A message should appear that it is now paired. Do not remove the cable before that.